# Can there ever be more than one program running on a single port?

Tags: sockets, networking, port

Can there ever be more than one program running on a single port? In other words, can two applications on the same server have the same port number?

Comment: Try running `new ServerSocket(10000);new ServerSocket(10000);`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Socket options SO\_REUSEADDR and SO\_REUSEPORT, how do they differ? Do they mean the same across all major operating systems?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14388706/socket-options-so-reuseaddr-and-so-reuseport-how-do-they-differ-do-they-mean-t)

Answer (score 3):

If they're bound to different IPs, yes. Binding to a port binds to both a IP address *and* a port number. So if application A is bound to `192.168.0.56:25565`, and application B is bound to `127.0.0.1:25565` they'll be no issue. But if application C wants to bind to either of those, or bind to `0.0.0.0:25565`, it'll be given a error.

Comment: How do you make applications on the same server bind to different IPs?

Comment: Depends on the language.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis In Java you can specify an `InetSocketAddress` to the various socket constructors; the interface address can be specified there.

Answer (score 2):

For TCP: Yes, as long as they are bound to different interfaces (e.g. `eth0` and `loopback`). On the same interface, no.

For UDP: Yes.

Comment: If I remember right, this is true for TCP, but not for UDP, but my recollection might be wrong.